# Are assignment submissions on paper obsolete?

Tags: homework

When students turn in papers, are they electronic? or do they turn in physical paper copies?

Perhaps there is one answer for high school students and another for college / graduate school?

Comment: There is one answer for each student in each course in each department in each university in each country in the world. I don't think this question can be answered.

Comment: what do you mean by student printers? Also, the tag "paper-submission" does not refer to homework submissions. It refers to journal submissions.

Answer (score 4):

Context: US universities. My daughter started 5 years ago now, taking her ink jet printer. It never got used - the small liberal arts school had lots of public printers in libraries and other buildings, with a page allowance that more than covered whatever printing needed to be done. Many professors took pdf submissions. Now at a large state school for grad work, nobody wants paper submissions.

Son just moved in as a freshman, no printer in tow.

Bottom line: universities have printing options available, usually with some pages included in your tuition, most profs take pdf submissions.

Answer (score 2):

Datapoint: I've been teaching for the last 10 years, always strongly encouraging digital submissions. They're easier to check for plagiarism, easier to handle, and more environmentally friendly. If I really need hardcopy (e.g. because they're more convenient to read), I can always print my own. None of my colleagues accepts hardcopy submissions only. But preferences certainly differ.